# spring-security: where did the Principal go?

Tags: spring-security, principal

I've been playing with spring-security for a while and for some reason I'm not able to access the principal in the JSPs even when authentication and authorization are working right.

This is my index.jsp:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>

<%@ page import="org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder" %>

<a href="forAuthenticated.jsp">for authenticated</a><br/>
<a href="admin/adminUsers.jsp">for admins</a>

<sec:authorize access="! isAuthenticated()">
    not logged in
</sec:authorize>
<sec:authorize access=" isAuthenticated()">
    logged in
</sec:authorize>

Your principal object is....: <sec:authentication property="principal.username" /><br/>
Authentication = <%=SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() %>

<p><a href="j_spring_security_logout">Logout</a></p>
```

And this is the *-security-xml:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
  xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

  <http pattern="/loggedout.jsp" security="none"/>
  <http pattern="/index.jsp"     security="none"/>
  <http pattern="/login.jsp"     security="none"/>

  <http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin/*"      access="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_SUPERUSER" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/forAuthenticated.jsp" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/logoutSuccess*" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**"          access="ROLE_USER" />

    <form-login login-page="/login.jsp" 
                authentication-failure-url = "/login.jsp?login_error=1"/>
    <logout logout-success-url="/loggedout.jsp" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"/>
    <session-management invalid-session-url="/sessionTimeout.htm" />
  </http>

  <global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>

  <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
   <authentication-provider>
    <user-service id="userDetailsService">
      <user name="username" password="password" authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" />
      <user name="test" password="test" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
    </user-service>
  </authentication-provider>
   </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

When I try to access the forAuthenticated.jsp I'm prompted for login. After entering test/test I access the forAuthenticated page, but not the admin/adminUsers.jsp. This is ok, but the problem is that I can't access the principal in the index.jsp. This is what index.jsp prints when logged in as test/test. Note that I can't see the `not logged in` nor `logged in` traces:

```
for authenticated
for admins 
Your principal object is....: 
null

Logout
```

What am I missing? what should I double-ckeck()?

Comment: Your index.jsp has security none try it on some other page which is secured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Karthikeyan suggests in his comment, the problem is the following line:

```
<http pattern="/index.jsp" security="none"/>
```

which effectively causes requests matching the given pattern to be dispatched straight to the handler method skipping the Spring Security filter chain. Not even the `SecurityContext` gets initialized in this case, so the authentication object won't be available for the `<sec:authorize>` tag based on which it should make  decision whether to reveal the wrapped content (and it obviously won't by default).

The [reference doc](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/appendix-namespace.html#nsa-http) states it clearly as well:

> A request pattern can be mapped to an empty filter chain, by setting this attribute (`security`) to none. No security will be applied and none of Spring Security's features will be available.

Instead of mapping an empty filter chain, you should simply allow anonymous access:

```
<sec:intercept-url pattern="/index.jsp" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
```

Comment: yes, that's was it. I had thought that, once authenticated, principal would be there for every request until logout

Comment: That's correct, since the authentication object gets basically stored in a http session attribute. The problem with `security="none"` is that it skips even the security filter (`SecurityContextPersistenceFilter`) which is responsible to initialize the thread-local `SecurityContextHolder` by reading the stored session attribute. It *is* still there, but there is nothing that would re-load it. Theoretically you could even get it manually from the session yourself...